# Javascript filter words containing numbers from an array

Tags: javascript

How can I get all words from an array that contain numbers in them?

```
var str = ["m2e", "you", "U2", "they#2", "someone"];
var filtered = str.filter(function (i) {
  // return i.includes('/\d/');
});

console.log(filtered); // m2e, U2, they#2
```

Nothing I try is working. Can you help?

Comment: `includes()` can only look for substrings and not regexp. You likely want to use `RegExp.test()`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside filter callback use `some` and `parseInt`. `...`is spread syntax to convert the string to array of characters `some` is used to check if any element in the array formed using `...` contains number

```js
var str = ["m2e", "you", "U2", "they#2", "someone"];
var filtered = str.filter(i => [...i].some(item => !isNaN(parseInt(item, 10)))
);

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = ["m2e", "you", "U2", "they#2", "someone"];
var onlyString = str.filter(function(i) {
  if (!/\d/.test(i)) {
    return i;
  }
});
console.log("onlyString");
console.log(onlyString);
var withNumericString = str.filter(function(i) {
  if (/\d/.test(i)) {
    return i;
  }
});
console.log("with Numeric String");
console.log(withNumericString);
```